# cmd command for renaming multiple files

Tags: cmd

I have many files in  folder in this format  `filefirst_131202.txt`, only the numbers after underscore changes.

i want to rename file as `filefirst_us_131202.txt`. i.e, add '_us' for all files in that folder.

tried executing the below command but it didn't work. Can anyone help please..

```
ren filefirst_*.txt filefirst_us_*.txt
expected Output : filefirst_us_131202.txt 
                  filefirst_us_131203.txt
```

Actual output after executing the command is:

```
filefirst_us_202.txt 
filefirst_us_203.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that there is only one underscore in the filenames:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir *_*.txt /b ') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%a_us_%%b"
```

Comment: That's good to hear.  In SO it's better to accept the answer that works for you - click the `tick` next to the answer.  In the future people can easily see if it worked for you.

Comment: am new to stackoverflow and this is the first question asked for.. and dint knew of this tick mark.. thanks for guiding..